# Create shape from typescript interface

Tags: typescript, class, interface

**Warning**: I've never used Typescript before.

I'm working with web components and I'm interested in creating a file that defines the properties (and potentially events) that will affect the component. I've done research on Typescript and I like the concise way it seems to be able to describe the shape of an object. This is what I have so far:

```
/* defining the keys (and which are optional) */
interface IX {
    hidden?: boolean;
    selected?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
    size?: 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl' | '2xl';
    onChange?: (event: any): void;
}

/* setting defaults */
export const ix: IX = {
    hidden: false,
    selected: false,
    disabled: false,
}
```

While I'm not currently using Typescript in my project (nor am I entirely convinced that I need to in order for this to work) I'm looking for a solution that would take a file that looks like the above and output some schema that defines the component's shape. Perhaps something like this:

```
export const ixShape = {
    hidden: {
          type: 'boolean',
          optional: true,
          'default': false,
    },
    /* and so on */
}
```

This can happen at build time, doesn't need to be run time. If I need a bundler like Rollup, I can leverage that also. What solutions are out there currently (if any)?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407154/is-there-code-generation-api-for-typescript