# Create object based on types typescript

Tags: typescript

Lest say I have this type

```
type foo = {
 go: string;
 start: string;
}
```

How can I dynamicaly made a function that will return

```
{ go: '', start: '' }
```

Is there any way on Type Script we could dynamically generate empty object based on solely just type? Or this is impossible because we cant just loop

I was thinking something like these

```
function generate<T>(T)<T>  {
 const obj = {}
 for (const key of keyof T) {
   obj[key] = ''
 }
 return obj
}
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. Types are *erased* when you compile TypeScript to JavaScript; you cannot use [reflection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-oop.html#reflection) to observe `foo` at runtime.  Why do you think you need this functionality? You can start building schema-like functionality so that there'd be an *object* like `const fooSchema = {go: "string", start: "string"} as const` and then [generate things from that](https://tsplay.dev/wj4X1m), but I don't know if you really are looking for that.  If you are, it needs to be built by someone.

Comment: Just out of curiosity ~  the problem Is I already had like a big interface that all of it is string. If I could loop over that interface I think I can just generate some value with it.

Comment: Well, you can't iterate over an interface with pure typescript; you would need to write or use a code generator like a TS transformer.  (e.g., https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-auto-mock ) If you want to just use TypeScript, you have to do it yourself at runtime.  Do you want [this beginning of a general schema solution](https://tsplay.dev/mbGEPW)?  Or do you want to [iterate over an array of key names](https://tsplay.dev/mAvJBW)?  I'm looking for guidance from you so that any answer I write will be focused and not twenty pages long (I tend to write long answers)

Comment: Thanks, I think the iterate over an array of key names are far more better for my problem.  It is small enough and doesnt need me to create a full object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the TypeScript compiler (`tsc`) to transpile TypeScript code into runnable JavaScript, the language's static type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types).  So your `Foo` type (renamed to uppercase to meet TS naming conventions) is not present in any form at runtime.  There is nothing you can iterate over to get the keys `go` and `start`.

---

The most straightforward way to get something to happen at runtime is to write the JavaScript necessary to do it, and then to make sure the TypeScript compiler can give you the strong types you need while you're writing it.  This is basically the *reverse* of what you're trying to do.

In your case: what does `generate()` need in order to work at runtime?  Well, if we can assume that the values generated by `generate()` will be objects holding only `string`-valued properties, then we need to pass it a list of the keys of the object.  So what if we write `generate()` to do that, and then define `Foo` in terms of the output of `generate()` instead of the other way around?

For example:

```
function generate<K extends PropertyKey>(...keys: K[]) {
  return Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, ""])) as { [P in K]: string };
}

const myFooObject = generate("go", "start");

type Foo = typeof myFooObject;
/* type Foo = {
    go: string;
    start: string;
} */

console.log(myFooObject)
/* {
  "go": "",
  "start": ""
} */
```

Here `generate()` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function that takes a list of keys (of type `K`) and produces a value of a type with keys in `K` and values of type `string`.  That `{[P in K]: string}` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) equivalent to `Record<K, string>` using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).

The implementation uses [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to build the object, and the return type is [asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to be the right type because TypeScript sees `Object.fromEntries()` as returning a type that's too wide for our purposes.

Anyway when you call `const myFooObject = generate("go", "start")`, it produces a value of type `{go: string; start: string}`, which is the same as your `Foo` type.  So we can just define `Foo` as `type Foo = typeof myFooObject` instead of doing it manually.  You *could* still do it manually, but the point I'm showing here is that it's much easier to write [DRY code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in TypeScript if you start with values and generate types from them, instead of trying to do it the other way around.

---

Again, if you are using the TypeScript compiler `tsc` as-is, then type erasure prevents you from writing `generate()` from the definition of `Foo`.  But...

If you are willing to add a build step to your project and perform [code generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407154/is-there-code-generation-api-for-typescript) using the [TypeScript compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) or something like it, you can then do arbitrary things with types.  There are libraries that do similar things to what you want; for example, [ts-auto-mock](https://typescript-tdd.github.io/ts-auto-mock/) claims to generate mock objects given an object type, which looks like exactly your use case.

Such an extra build step might be a reasonable approach for you, but if you go down that route you should note that you're not using just plain TypeScript anymore (and therefore the topic is probably out of scope for a question with just a TypeScript tag).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZlQJwIZVQHgGlFUAPPMAEwGdEAFTOAByygE9DU2A+ACgDpBAay7UAXIkIBtALoBKRAG8AsAChEiTKighMSAPIAjAFapo-YIwC2AUTBRMMVNV4i21flexNXiALzciFJCADSIAETh8grYtIpBdIgwSIQyEtQOyciIAL4A3Go5amoQCBmIVmwAYnBwRqbQ-ijoWLiovOHIcOFh4RnYmFDhcgWqauwsiDVwTROocMAV1bX1ZlCjAPQAVIhzU7VNKuoaKHDpmWDIoyeI-YPnjpejOYhbG8WqpWDUcAA2qPxfnBkLxKtNVtA5Gptko1BpOt0JJEQnCInchkjwoVXu8xqogA)

Answer (score 2):

You could make it generic, like this:

```
type foo<T extends string = string> = {
    go: T;
    start: T;
}

const test: foo<''> = {
    go: '',
    start: '',
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAZg9nAPAFShAHsCA7AJgZyn2ACcBLbAcygF4jSLKA+WqAbwCgpupK4AuKMgDcXHsQCGJYIJEcAvhw6hIaALZhQAMQSt4SAOQGmojgGM42YlCzFBEDdt11OPXgKhGANGO6Tpgt4KokA)

Comment: This won't generate an object from a type.